# Task repeating?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, async-await

Previously, when making a looping task it would run perfectly the first time and fall apart because of the timing problems, such as the functions of one individual task would start running faster than another, even though it was programmed to come before that task.

So my idea to figure out a way to repeat the events of a task once the delays(times) have ended, in my head it would go something like this:

```
private async Task programCore()
{
    int n = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; )
    {
         FirstThing(); 
         await Task.Delay(2100);

         SecondThing();
         await Task.Delay(2200);

         ThirdThing();
         await Task.Delay(2300);
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    else if (programCore.TasksHaveAllTimedOut) // Idealistic code.
    {
        programCore.Restart();
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible? If not, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What if the thing you are waiting on takes longer than 2100ms?

Comment: It doesn't. 2100ms could be considered beyond the time it needs.

Comment: Sounds dodgy to me. What are you waiting for?

Comment: That's a bad assumption to make.  Why not just make `FirstThing()`, etc, `async` and `await` those?

Comment: @CodingGorilla , What do you mean? I'm fairly new to C#.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do those things do? Why can't you let them tell you when they finish? Why do you think 2s will be always enough?

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
private async Task programCore()
{
    int n = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; )
    {
        await FirstThing(); 
        await SecondThing();
        await ThirdThing();
   }
}

private async Task FirstThing()
{
    // Do something here
}

private async Task SecondThing()
{
    // Do something here
}

private async Task ThirdThing()
{
    // Do something here
}
```

This has the effect that it runs `FirstThing`, waits for it to finish, then runs `SecondThing`, waits for it to finish, then finally runs `ThirdThing` and waits for it to finish before repeating the loop.

Comment: Please flag it as the "answer"

Answer (score 5):

I believe @CodingGorilla has the right idea. Your code should look something like this (using `CancellationToken`s for timeouts):

```
private async Task programCore()
{
  int n = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    var timeout1 = new CancellationTokenSource(2100);
    await FirstThingAsync(timeout1.Token);

    var timeout2 = new CancellationTokenSource(2200);
    await SecondThingAsync(timeout2.Token);

    var timeout2 = new CancellationTokenSource(2300);
    await ThirdThingAsync(timeout3.Token);
  }
}
```

The code above will raise an exception if any task exceeds its timeout, which may not be exactly what you want. You can catch the `OperationCanceledException` if you wish to handle this differently.

Comment: This is good if he needs to be able to cancel or allow the tasks to "Timeout".  I think the OP was just using the delay to wait for the other tasks to finish.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: I reread the question and I believe you are correct; the OP is not needing a timeout. +1 to you!